# Question regarding conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Suppose 10% of the people are good at art, and that 40% of the people who are good at art are also good at math. If a person is not good at art, they have only a 30% chance of being good at math. What is the probability that a person who is good at math will also be good at art?

Is my solution correct?:

Let M be person being good at math and A be good at art. Then A’ is being not good at art

P(A)=0.1

P(M|A)= 0.4

P(M|A’)=0.3

So P(M)=0.4+0.3=0.7

By bayes theorem: P(A|M)=0.4*0.1/0.7=0.06

Comment: What have you tried ? where are you stuck ? It's not a homework service : [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @Surb oh sorry ill edit in my solution

Comment: Your answer is not correct. Drawing a probability tree will solve your question. You may aslo assume that there are 100 people in total and create a 2 by 2 table to help you understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a figure is worth 1000 words:

[image]

So consider just the "good at math" area.  What proportion of *that* is also "good at art"?

Comment: Im getting 4/31 for this. Hmm makes sense

Comment: Then maybe a $\checkmark$ (or at minimum +1) is in order.

Comment: Nice answer. (+1)